# DQL with JOIN Doctrine2 and Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, join, doctrine-orm

Hello I have two tables: products and stocks. They have manyToOne relation and look this way:

Stock:

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+ 
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| stock_name | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| address    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Products:

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| stock_id | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| name     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| delivery | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Entities

```
class Products
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $delivery;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Stock", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $stock;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $name
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getDelivery()
    {
        return $this->delivery;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $delivery
     */
    public function setDelivery($delivery)
    {
        $this->delivery = $delivery;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getStock()
    {
        return $this->stock;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $stock
     */
    public function setStock(Stock $stock)
    {
        $this->stock = $stock;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}

class Stock
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $stock_name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $address;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(
     *      targetEntity="Products",
     *      mappedBy="stock",
     *      orphanRemoval=true
     * )
     */
    private $products;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getStockName()
    {
        return $this->stock_name;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $stock_name
     */
    public function setStockName($stock_name)
    {
        $this->stock_name = $stock_name;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAddress()
    {
        return $this->address;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $address
     */
    public function setAddress($address)
    {
        $this->address = $address;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getProducts()
    {
        return $this->products;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $products
     */
    public function setProducts($products)
    {
        $this->products = $products;
    }
}
```

I need sql that gives me all delivery addresses which associated with stock id 1 and add to this array only one stock address under id 1 from table Stock. The array should look like:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Stock Address
    [1] => delivery1
    [2] => delivery2
    [3] => delivery3
)
```

I try this statement but it gives multiply stock address and array in array:

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
    "SELECT o.delivery , p.address
        FROM AppBundle:Products o 
        JOIN o.stock p
        WHERE o.stock =1
    ");

return $qb->getScalarResult();
```

and the result of this statement:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [delivery] => Spoon str, USA 
        [address] => Wall street 1, USA 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [delivery] => Lincoln street, USA 
        [address] => Wall street 1, USA 
    )
)
```

Comment: You talk about doctrine. Where are your entity definitions?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to retrieve the array you want directly via one DQL statement. The reason is that you actually want the four rows that are fetched in your example to be from two different columns.

So you need to process the result somehow. For example you could change your snippet to:

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
"SELECT o.delivery , p.address
    FROM AppBundle:Products o 
    JOIN o.stock p
    WHERE o.stock = 1
");

$result = $qb->getScalarResult();

return array_merge([$result[0]['address']], array_column($result, 'delivery'));
```

So you take the address as the first element of the array to be returned and add the delivery column only of all results and add them as well.